# how to play a .wav file using QSound in qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I tried using QSound in my project but I am getting an undefined refrence to `_imp_ZN6Q`:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtMultimedia/QSound>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QSound player;
    QSound::play("E:\songs");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: What's the **exact** error message you get? Add **all of it** to your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project file (.pro) add

```
QT += multimedia
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does?

Comment: It tells QT to include the QT multimedia module in your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
QT += multimedia
```

and add :

```
#include <QtMultimedia/QSound>

    QSound newMessage("sound/newChat.wave");
    newMessage.play();
```